# Transfer time series data from PySpark to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Spark Cluster and a Cassandra cluster. In pyspark I read a csv file then transform it to an RDD. I then go through every row in my RDD and use a mapper and reducer function. I end up getting the following output (I've made this list short for demonstration purposes):

```
[(u'20170115', u'JM', u'COP'), (u'20170115', u'JM', u'GOV'), (u'20170115', u'BM', u'REB'), (u'20170115', u'OC', u'POL'), (u'20170114', u'BA', u'EDU')]
```

I want to go through each row in the array above and store each tuple into one table in Cassandra. I want the unique key to be the date. Now I know that I can turn this array into a dataframe and then store it into Cassandra (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md#saving-a-dataframe-in-python-to-cassandra). If I turn the list into a dataframe and then store it into Cassandra will Cassandra still be able to handle it? I guess I'm not fully understanding how Cassandra stores values. In my array the dates are repeated, but the other values are different.

What is the best way for me to store the data above in Cassandra? Is there a way for me to store data directly from Spark to Cassandra using python?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of DSE 4.x supported RDDs, but the current connector for DSE and open source Cassandra is "limited to DataFrame only operations."

[PySpark with Data Frames](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md)

You stated "I want the unique key to be the date".  I assume you mean partion key, since date is not unique in your example.  Its ok to use date as the partion key (assuming partitons will not be too large) but your primary key needs to be unique.